# Checking if user is logged in the templates

Tags: php, twig

Let's say I do something like this:

```
if (IsUserLoggedIn()) {
    echo $twig->render('home.html');
} else {
    echo $twig->render('login.html');
}

function isuserloggedin()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['userId']);
}
```

Is it a security issue not checking in the template... Or should it per-bases be fine?

Template:

```
Yo, you're logged in here, some details that only logged in should be able to see..
```

What I am asking is it essential to use some kind of conditional if statement in the Twig template to make sure again the user is logged in?

Cheers.

Comment: If the only way to get to the twig templates (apart from `login.html`) is by being logged in then I think you're fine. The user has to pass the first login check so I don't think you need to include a second. The only potential issue is if you're using an unreliable/insecure method of checking the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine logic.

Depending on how granular your user permissions are (for example, if you have regular user, power user and administrator), you can pass that permission level into the Twig template and display sections of the page based on those variables.